# Why my button doesnt return the values and doest show my image at all

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import memeData from "./memeData";

export default function Meme(){

    const [memeImage, setMemeImage] = React.useState("")

    function getMemeImage(){
        const memesArray = memeData.data.memes
        const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * memesArray.length)
        setMemeImage(memesArray[randomNumber].url)

    }


    return(
        <div>
            <form className="form">
                <input type="text" className="form-input" placeholder="Top Text" />
                <input type="text" className="form-input" placeholder="Bottom Text" />
                <button className="btn" onClick={getMemeImage}>Get a new meme image </button>
            </form>
            <img src={memeImage} alt="memes"></img>
        </div>
    )
}
```

So when i click the button it should add new image but it just return an empty string and the icon of img when it isnt working

Comment: Hello. Show us the `memeData`

Comment: export default {
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "memes": [
            {
                "id": "181913649",
                "name": "Drake Hotline Bling",
                "url": "https://i.imgflip.com/30b1gx.jpg",
                "width": 1200,
                "height": 1200,
                "box_count": 2
            },
            {
                "id": "87743020",
                "name": "Two Buttons",
         "url": "https://i.imgflip.com/1g8my4.jpg",
         "width": 600,
          "height": 908,
          "box_count": 3
            }
        ]
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

The *data* you provided looks fine. I believe the problem you are facing is auto-refreshing website with every button click, because your button is wrapped with `form`. The default button *type* is `submit`, that's why you are not able to display the image. Simply change it's type to `button`.

```
<button type="button" className="btn" onClick={getMemeImage}>Random img</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much its working perfectly right now and im new to react and  i was stuck for hours